# How do I target nested JSON objects in php, and echo them?

Tags: php, json

Okay, so I think you get what I wanna do by just watching the code.

```
//Get JSON text file (Steam API)
$json = file_get_contents('http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=57690');

//Decode JSON
$game_json = json_decode($json, true);

//Target game name and echo it
echo $game_json['name'];
```

The JSON itself comes in this order (unstructured, very sorry):

```
{"57690":{"success":true,"data":{"type":"game","name":"Tropico 4: Steam Special Edition"
```

So my target is `""name":"Tropico 4: Steam Special Edition""`, which is what I want to echo on my page. I'm not sure if it helps, but `"name":` appears once, is something like `[0]` needed in my code to target the first? Is the nesting what's stopping me here, or is the `$game_json['name'];` an incorrect way of targeting?

ANY tips and/or help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the future, use `print_r($game_json)` to check the `array` structure.

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=57690');
$game_json = json_decode($json, true);
echo $game_json['57690']['data']['name'];
//Tropico 4: Steam Special Edition
echo $game_json['57690']['data']['required_age'];
//0
//etc...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are much too kind. A little bit new to this, even the easiest of tutorials (the duplicate mark, for instance) are too confusing.

Comment: You're very welcome @JohnSmith. You'll get there! persistence is the key :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as the correct answer, thank you !

Comment: Of course, but can't do it instantly, waiting for a timer!

Comment: How do I make API text readable? Structured, not a long series of text. Tools?

Comment: can you please elaborate further ?

Comment: @JohnSmith Mark this as the answer. Don't hold him hostage while you ask completely irrelevant, random questions in the comments section.

Comment: @PedroLobito Well it's just one long text on the same row. Any good idea on how to view it with indents and spaces? Any recommended tools?

Comment: @NateI Ohhhh no, sorry if it appeared that way. The "best answer" was coming, was just waiting for the timer (I think it's 10 mins) so that I actually could select a best answer at all. Didn't wanna make another post here for a stupid question, figured that Pedro might know something about it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

//This is your json string
$string = {"57690":{"success":true,"data":{"type":"game","name":"Tropico 4: Steam Special Edition"...

//Turn JSON string into object
$data = json_decode($string);

//Turn your object into an array (easier to work with in this case)
$data = (Array)$data;

//Get name of item with "57690" key
$name = $data["57690"]->data->name;

//Echo the name
echo($name);

//You can also echo out all names of all items like this:
foreach($data as $key => $item)
{
    echo($item->data->name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I get the concept now! While I'm typing I might aswell ask, how do I structure this API so it's readable? It's just one long series of text looking in the browser..

Comment: depending on your editor, you may have built-in features or plugins available to auto-format JSON. I use Notepad++ and there is a plugin called "JSON Viewer" that auto-formats for me.

Comment: Perfect, just what I'm looking for. This community is too scrub-friendly. Thanks.